# Routing to Controller fails in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to register my controllers in Laravel 4. In `routes.php` I have:

```
Route::get("/","HomeController@index");
Route::get("search","SearchController@index");
```

Now, the home controller route is fine, but the search controller route gives me an error:

```
ReflectionException: Class SearchController does not exist
```

However, the class *does* exist. I even tried to create another sample controller, but to no avail, as the same message came up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

names are case sensitive in L4. And the method name should match exactly(e.g. getIndex, not index() ).

Also, because it uses composer packages, you will need to run:

`php composer dump-autoload`

 to detect any new classes/controllers

Comment: Thanks! it was a indeed the composer issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and  composer `dump-autoload` did not resolve it.

I realized that my class file was not declared in vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php generated by Composer.

I cleared the contents of the cache folder. In Linux, this folder is:
~/.composer/cache 
and in Windows 7: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Composer\files
If  bootstrap/compiled.php is present, it should also be removed, or run: `php artisan clear-compiled`.

After this, I removed composer.lock and the vendor folder and run: composer install. 
This put my class file into autoload_classmap.php however the ReflectionException was still being thrown...

As a final try, I copied and renamed another controller from the project that was already in use, and this resolved the problem.

Comment: A simple way to do the same using composer is to comment-out references to the controller in routes.php, run ```php artisan dump``` and then un-comment those references.