# ReflectionException Class SearchController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having the problem in 
[Routing to Controller fails in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201269/routing-to-controller-fails-in-laravel-4)
except none of those solutions help. I ran the dump-autoload. HomeController still works.

Ive been at this for an hour now and I haven't had this problem in previous version of Laravel. Getting very frustrated.

What bothers me is that the autoload_classmap contains the path for the SearchController, yet I still get the ReflectionException... I don't have any typos I've checked everything so many times now.

If I move SearchController.php it gives me a `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` so clearly it read the file.

```
<?
class SearchController extends BaseController {

    public function index() {
        return View::make('search.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you put your SearchController.php file?

Comment: app/controllers right next to BaseController

Comment: if I move SearchController.php it gives me the "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" error so clearly it read the file yet still didn't find the controller. I'll post the controller up in the question

Comment: With those updates, if you say it's still not working then my suggestion would be to redo the route and recreate the file from scratch. Sometimes it is a typo, just one that's hard to see ;)

PS. You want to use <?php, not <? (and I guess that is your error right here... I get that message if I replace <?php with <?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `<?php` not `<?`.